# Custom Action bar onclick does not work for async task - android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, action

I have a custom action bar and onclick attached to it which runs in the background , for some strange reason my app force closes .
I am doing a network operation in doinbackground
Attached below is the code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.enroll);


final ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(enroll.this);

final View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar_enroll, null);
TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text1);
mTitleTextView.setText("True Tracer");
String fontPath = "fonts/stasmic_.ttf";
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);
mTitleTextView.setTypeface(tf);

final ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) mCustomView
    .findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
tpass=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tip);
otp1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.otp1);

pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
String samp=pref.getString("mynumber", null);
tpass.setText("Self authentication SMS sent \n with activation code to  "+samp);
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {

    backend runner = new backend();
    runner.execute();
    }
});
    }


class backend extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Result>
{

    @Override
    protected Result doInBackground(String... params) {
do something();
}
}
```

Comment: Post your logcat errors

Comment: have you mentioned network permission in manifest file?

Comment: am running it on my mobile ..not sure how to get logcat

Answer (score 0):

In your on click, call async task like this

```
           new backend().execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you declaring that your asynctask expects parameters of type String but then you don't send any arguments when you call execute? Also, doInBackground returns an object of type Result. What are you doing with that object in onPostExecute? Two things are important to know what the problem is: the exception and what you are doing in your AsyncTask.